# Optimizing sparse matrix solve time

Tags: sparse-matrix

Our simulations have large very sparse sets of SPD equations (a resistive network with current sources). We solve Ax = b, where A is conductance matrix and b is the current vector. We have effective solution methods (Eigen/sparse and/or Tim Davis's LDL). During the simulation, only a few of the elements in A change between time steps, but we need to factorize the entire matrix for the new solution (though we can avoid the ordering step in many cases).

We are wondering if there are methods that could segregate the fixed portion in A from the dynamic portions, factorize the fixed portions separately from the dynamic, then combine the two for the solution (forward/back substitution). From a top level understanding of standard solution methods, my sense is that this is not possible. But .... ??
Thanks in advance
Kevin